# Usage of malloc and free

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to decode an mp4 video into YUV frames. I want to allocate memory for each frame to be decoded, is it OK if I continuously allocate memory and free it. Is there any problem in doing so (ie, contentiously allocating and freeing memory using `malloc` and `free`)?

Comment: If you do so, you may face performance issues... otherwise it is technically correct.

Answer (score 5):

I would be better to allocate sufficient buffer once and reuse the same buffer. Other than some performance hit, repeated malloc-free doesn't pose any problems.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, there's no problem with that at all as long as you don't try to access memory that you've already freed.

On the other hand, making all these calls repeatedly creates an overhead that you could (and should) avoid by allocating a sufficient amount of memory ahead of time, and then free it all at the end.

The approach of repeatedly allocating/freeing should really only be used if you are under very tight memory constraints, otherwise, reserve a big block of memory and allocate parts of it as you need yourself. Or alternatively, if possible, reuse the same chunk of memory.

Update: As mentioned by @EricPostpischil in a helpful comment (see below), malloc is a *library* call, not a system call which would only happen when the current heap is exhausted. For more information on this see [this explanation](http://bit.ly/NrxZi0)

Comment: @downvoters .. what's with the downvotes? Could I please have an explanation? Downvotes *without* explanation doesn't help anyone (OP, SO or me).

Comment: @Lundin Thanks .. I mean, I like to click buttons and watch things change on the screen just as much as the next person, but seriously, sometimes people just seem trigger happy. And I really don't see the purpose of a downvote without any comment/reason/suggestion(!), no one's going to benefit from that in any sort of way.

Comment: malloc is a library call, not a system call. Any decent implementation makes a system call only when the currently allocated heap is exhausted. With repeated malloc and free of the same size, that will not happen. A good implementation may also support this case with low overhead.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right, thanks for the clarification re library vs system call, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects that you allocate have the same size, there shouldn't be much of a performance hit. In case of doubt, measure it.

Correctly tracking allocated memory is often not trivial, so it is probably easier to allocate  a buffer once and use this throughout your program. But here the principal rule should be to use what corresponds to the logic of your program, is the easiest to read and to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Constantly mallocing and freeing is will not break the program, but it will cause a lot of performance issues, especially since you say you're going to be doing it every frame. Mallocing and freeing that often can cause a noticeable performance decrease.

What you can do is just malloc the memory once, and then re-use the same allocation for each frame. If you don't need to store the memory after you've done what you want with the frame before the next frame is read, there isn't any problem.